What is this part for and what is it called?
I recently bought angel lights for my BMW F30 and now it's time to install it. I have already figured out what other electronic components are needed for, but I don’t know what this one is for. Please tell me.


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

That's a 3M Scotchlok IDC (Insulation Displacement Connector) or a knockoff. It's used to safely tap into power from a passing wire without cutting, stripping or worrying about a short circuit.
They come in various sizes (usually indicated by different colors) and it's important to use the correct size connector for the wires that are being spliced. The genuine 3M models have the wire size range in text molded into the part.
Here are instructions from 3M for one particular size that they make.

